# populating multiple comboboxes on tabcontrol in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, tabs, tabcontrol

I am populating multiple Combo Boxes on multiple pages of `Tabcontrol`, while this approach works fine for combo boxes on the form, it doesn't work for populating combo boxes on `TabControl`

```
For Each tab_page As Control In Me.TabControl1.TabPages
    For Each temp_ctrl As Control In tab_page.Controls
        If temp_ctrl.GetType.ToString = "System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox" Then
            temp_cmb = CType(Me.Controls(temp_ctrl.Name), ComboBox)
            For Each r As DataRow In dtab_KPI.Rows
                temp_cmb.Items.Add(r(0))
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Why are you looking up the Control in the Controls collection when you already have the control object. Try `temp_cmb = CType(temp_ctrl, ComboBox)`.

Comment: Thanks @Blackwood, it worked